# how to show parameters json received from ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have just receive this json from .ajax function of jQuery

```
string(626) "[{"ID":"6032","post_author":"2276","post_date":"2011-07-27 00:00:00","post_date_gmt":"2011-07-27 00:00:00","post_content":"","post_title":"Web Developer\/Programmer","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"closed","ping_status":"closed","post_password":"","post_name":"web-developerprogrammer","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2012-05-03 09:25:32","post_modified_gmt":"2012-05-03 13:25:32","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":"4459","guid":"http:\/\/startupchile.dev\/joinastartup\/web-developerprogrammer\/","menu_order":"0","post_type":"jobman_job","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0"}]"
```

How to i can display some parameters for html ?. for example only display ID,post_title ?

This is my code:

```
(function($){
```

```
    $('#searchjob').keypress(function(e){
        var search = $.trim($(this).val());

        if (e.which == "13") {

            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //$('#loading').html(<img src="rutagif" alt="loading" />);
                },
                url:"../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data:{ action: 'searching_job',data : search },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }

            });

            e.preventDefault();

        };

    });

 })(jQuery);
```

I can fixed my error. The json from PHP is wrong (I'm use to var_dump, now use to print_r). I  just share the code that worked success.

```
(function($){

    $('#searchjob').keypress(function(e){
        var search = $.trim($(this).val());

        if (e.which == "13") {

            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //$('#loading').html();
                },
                url:"../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data:{ action: 'searching_job',data : search },
                //dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    var jsonresult = JSON.parse(data);

                    $.each(jsonresult, function(i, item){
                        alert(jsonresult[i].post_title);
                    });
                }

            });

            e.preventDefault();

        };

    });

 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: I assume what you've shown in the question is some kind of console output - please show your actual JavaScript code. jQuery's Ajax functions normally parse a JSON response automatically (especially if you used the `dataType:"json"` option), so then you can access the properties directly. If for some reason you actually have a JSON string you can explicitly parse it with `yourData = JSON.parse(thatString)` or `yourData = $.parseJSON(thatString)`. In your data you seem to have an array with one element, so you'd say `yourData[0]["ID"]` or `yourData[0].ID`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have just add the code.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have just try using data[0]["ID"] but not found :/

Comment: `data[0]["ID"]` should work within your success callback assuming your PHP is correctly outputting the data you originally showed without the `string(626)` part or the outermost double-quotes, i.e., `[{"ID":"6032","post_author":"2276","post_date":"2011-07-27 00:00:00", /*etc*/,"comment_count":"0"}]`. What does the `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: Yes show data. The I'm returning PHP data from var_dump(json_encode($result));. Can you give any example ?

Comment: I have just fixed my error. In my code PHP I use to var_dump for display the data. Now I use to print_r. Now I can use yourData[0]["ID"] for display success my data.